# Need help to prove $(R\circ S \circ R)^n \subseteq (R \circ S)^n \circ R$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

There is a relation $R$ and $S$ on set $U$. Given $R$ is transitive.

I need to prove  $(R\circ S \circ R)^n \subseteq (R \circ S)^n \circ R$ for all $n \geq 1 $

---

My Attempt:-
Tried doing this by induction

for base case $n=1$  its trivial as $(R\circ S \circ R)^1 \subseteq (R \circ S)^1 \circ R = (R\circ S \circ R) \subseteq (R \circ S) \circ R$

Took Induction Step as : $(R\circ S \circ R)^n \subseteq (R \circ S)^n \circ R$

now for $n=n+1$

$(R\circ S \circ R)^{n+1} $

$R\circ S \circ R \circ (R\circ S \circ R)^n $  $\qquad$ { Def. of exponents }

$\subseteq R\circ S \circ R \circ (R\circ S)^n \circ R$  $\qquad$ { Using $I.H$ and monotonicity }

I am stuck here and do not know how to proceed further. Can anybody try to help me by providing a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Expand $(R\circ S\circ R)^{n+1}$ the other way,

$$(R\circ S\circ R)^{n+1}=(R\circ S\circ R)^n\circ R\circ S\circ R\subseteq(R\circ S)^n\circ R\circ R\circ S\circ R\;,$$

and apply the transitivity of $R$ to $R\circ R$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are absolutely right. It works the other way as you mentioned.

Comment: @TechJ: You’re welcome.